# Remove [i] link when checked in the filter box

Tags: html, css

I've created a filterbox to show all selected checked texts in a box. When you click the checkbox the item automatically displays into the box. At this point, I'm trying to remove the [i] beside the text when its in the filter box, but I'm experiencing difficulty.

```js
const check = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-content li');
const checkBox = Array.from(check);
const filtersDisplay = document.querySelector('.search-menu .filter-box');

const defaultText = "Selected filters will display here";
const selected = new Set();

function showValues(set) {
  if (set.size === 0) filtersDisplay.textContent = defaultText;
  else {
    filtersDisplay.innerHTML = "";
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (let el of set) {
      const btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.textContent = (el);
      fragment.appendChild(btn);
    }
    filtersDisplay.appendChild(fragment);
  }
}

checkBox.forEach(function(list) {
  list.addEventListener('change', function(el) {
    const text = list.textContent.trim();
    if (selected.has(text)) {
      selected.delete(text)
    } else selected.add(text)
    showValues(selected);
  })
})
```

```html
 <div class="search-menu">
    <h2>Search Menu</h2>
      <input class="search-bar"type="search" placeholder="Search..">
        <button class="search-bar-button">Go</button>

    <p class="filter-box">Selected filters will display here</p>
  <!-- Catagories List -->

<br>

   <p class="description-prompt">Click ℹ️ to get description of content</p>

    <button class="accordion">Catagories</button>
    <ul class="accordion-content">
          <li>
            <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" >Item1
            </label>
                    <a onclick="Alert.render('Natural Systems are...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus, dolore.')" >ℹ️</a>
          </li>    

            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />Item2
                </label>
                    <a onclick="Alert.render('Social Systems are...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus, dolore.')" >ℹ️</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />Item3
                </label>
                    <a onclick="Alert.render('Sustainability Systems are...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus, dolore.')">ℹ️</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply replace ℹ️ with empty string '' before adding to set.

```
const text = list.textContent.replace('ℹ️', '').trim();
```

Complete function –

```
checkBox.forEach(function(list) {
        list.addEventListener('change', function(el) {
          const text = list.textContent.replace('ℹ️', '').trim();

          if (selected.has(text)) {
            selected.delete(text)
          } else selected.add(text)
          showValues(selected);
        })
      })
```

Comment: Thank you @Junaid Hamza, the solution worked. The trim() method is not needed but I still think its good just remove unanticipated white spaces in the text.